# How to parse a Quoted Post from vBulletin?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, vbulletin, quote

Using PHP, how can I transform:

```
[QUOTE=Username;1234]This is the text being quoted[/QUOTE]
```

Into:

```
<div class="quote"><a href="./linktopost?id=1234>Posted by: Username</a><p>This is the text being quoted.</p></div>
```

Notice where the **Username**, **1234** id, and **This is the text being quoted** text are mapped to.

I know how to do the beginning and end, by simply replacing (e.g. `str_replace`) any instance of:

```
[QUOTE= >>> <div class="quote">< href="./linktopost.php?id=

[/QUOTE] >>> </p><div>
```

but I don't know how to extract the **Username**, **Post ID**, and the **Text** being quoted so that I can tie them all together.

If it helps, from what I can tell above, the username can be extracted between the delimiters `[QUOTE=` and `;`, the post id can be extracted between `;` and `]`, and the text can be extracted between `]` and `[/QUOTE]`, but I don't know how to extract them.

Also, what happens if there is a quote within a quote?  The solution should also work in those cases as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to parse BBCode you might find life easier if you use something like the [PEAR parser](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser/download).

Comment: @John C: Thanks, but the PEAR parser does not seem to handle [QUOTE] tags.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help ;)

```
$str = "[QUOTE=Username;1234]This is the text being quoted[/QUOTE]";

if(preg_match('/\[QUOTE=([^;]+);([0-9]+)\]([^\[]+)\[\/QUOTE\]/i', $str, $matches)){
    echo "<br>USERNAME : ".$matches[1];
    echo "<br>POST ID : ".$matches[2];
    echo "<br>MESSAGE : ".$matches[3];
}
```